# How can I turn a normal string into to a verbatim string without effecting `\"`?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core

I'm trying to read a file and run each line through a process, and I want to use @"" for each of them, but any time I try to edit each line to work in a verbatim string, it always makes \" => ", and I cant find any way to prevent it.

Is this even possible?

Comment: A verbatim string is a representation of a string in code. Text read from a file is not in code (i.e. a compilation unit), so unless you're producing string expressions (such as generating code), it's unclear what you're trying to do and why. Note that the debugger will always show strings in the non-verbatim form, even if your code uses a verbatim string, as the `String` type does not include representation information.

Comment: I think what you are seeing is actually in the StringDebuggerVisualizer and is not actually in the file. The Visualizer put escape sequences if there's double quote with in the string content but they don't actually exist in the file content. 
Just assuming the way you described the problem.

Comment: Are you building extension for VS or having trouble to see values in VS while editing/debugging? Please [edit] to clarify why your question need "visual-studio" tag (hopefully you had chance to read ["info"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) on the tag before adding it).

Comment: Could you show the use case you read? And explain what are you going to use them for? Maybe we can meet your needs.